# Slice each string row of pandas dataframe according a pattern array

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, slice

I need to slice a string row of pandas in different positions, and I want to use vectorization for that. Some one can help me?
Each line has this pattern:

```
012016010402AAPL34      010APPLE       DRN          R$  000000000415000000000042200000000004150000000000421300000000042080000000003950000000000435000005000000000000012500000000000052664400000000000000009999123100000010000000000000BRAAPLBDR004115
```

This line has 26 diferent information separated by chars, for example:

```
['01', '2016/01/04', '02', 'AAPL34      ', ...,'115']
```

The string position os each data is define by this array: `[0,2,10,12,24,27,39,49,52,56,69,82,95,108,121,134,147,152,170,188,201,202,210,217,230,242,245]`

I tried unsuccessfully to use this function with the dataframe:

```
def row_slice(s,indices):
    return pd.Series([s[i:j] for i,j in zip(indices, indices[1:]+[None])])
```

The data that I'm using can be downloaded by this [link](https://www.b3.com.br/data/files/9C/F3/01/C4/297BE410F816C9E492D828A8/SeriesHistoricas_DemoCotacoesHistoricas12022003.zip):

Someone can help me?

Comment: Can you provide a DataFrame constructor of a short sample?

Comment: Each line should be like this (as a dict): {'line[0:2]': '01', 'line[2:10]': '20160104', 'line[10:12]': '02', 'line[12:24]': 'AAPL34      ', 'line[24:27]': '010', 'line[27:39]': 'APPLE       ', 'line[39:49]': 'DRN       ', 'line[49:52]': '   ', 'line[52:56]': 'R$  ', 'line[56:69]': '0000000004150', 'line[69:82]': '0000000004220', 'line[82:95]': '0000000004150', 'line[95:108]': '0000000004213', 'line[108:121]': '0000000004208', 'line[121:134]': '0000000003950', 'line[134:147]': '0000000004350', 'line[147:152]': '00005', 'line[152:170]': '000000000000012 ...

Comment: Please edit your question and include this information formatted correctly in the question body.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need [`pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html), reading your file directly:

```
l = [0,2,10,12,24,27,39,49,52,56,69,82,95,108,121,134,147,152,170,188,201,202,210,217,230,242,245]

import numpy as np
df = pd.read_fwf('filename', widths=np.diff(l), header=None)
```

Output:

```
   0         1   2       3   4      5    6   7   8     9   ...  16     17  \
0   1  20160104   2  AAPL34  10  APPLE  DRN NaN  R$  4150  ...   5  12500   

         18             19  20        21       22             23  \
0  52664400  000000000000d   i  fferent3  1000000  1000000000000   

             24   25  
0  0BRAAPLBDR00  411  

[1 rows x 26 columns]
```

With leading zeros (as string), add the `dtype=str` parameter:

```
   0         1   2       3    4      5    6    7   8              9   ...  \
0  01  20160104  02  AAPL34  010  APPLE  DRN  NaN  R$  0000000004150  ...   

      16                  17                  18             19 20        21  \
0  00005  000000000000012500  000000000052664400  000000000000d  i  fferent3   

        22             23            24   25  
0  1000000  1000000000000  0BRAAPLBDR00  411  

[1 rows x 26 columns]
```

Comment: If leading zeros are important, include: `dtype=str` when reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use something similar to this:

```
df['col name'].str.extractall('(\d{2})(\d{8})(\d{2})([A-Z]{4}\d{2})')
```

Output:

```
0   1   2   3
match               
0   0   01  20160104    02  AAPL34
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to split the string into a list of substrings according to `indices`:

```py
lst = [s[indices[i]:indices[i+1]].strip() for i in range(len(indices) - 1)]
```

Output:

```
['01', '20160104', '02', 'AAPL34', '010', 'APPLE', 'DRN', '', 'R$', '0000000004150', '0000000004220', '0000000004150', '0000000004213', '0000000004208', '0000000003950', '0000000004350', '00005', '000000000000012500', '000000000052664400', '000000000000d', 'i', 'fferent3', '1000000', '1000000000000', '0BRAAPLBDR00', '411']
```

Comment: @Thiago Olinek Reinehr Do you need any additional help with your question?